# Make a button disable at clicked but enable until countdown isn't zero

Tags: javascript

```
function counter2(){
var counter =10;
var on=document.getElementById("bet");
setInterval(function(){
counter--;
if(counter==9){
    on.innerHTML = "";
    
    }
if(counter>=0){
    id=document.getElementById("res");
    var bet=document.getElementById("pts");
        
        var beth=document.getElementById("beth");
        var betv=document.getElementById("betv");
    id.innerHTML="Bet within&nbsp;" +counter + "&nbsp;seconds";;
    beth.disabled = false; //Beth is both Function and button //
    beth.style.backgroundColor = "#4CAF50";
    betv.disabled = false;
    betv.style.backgroundColor = "#008CBA";
    beth.style.cursor = 'pointer'; 
    betv.style.cursor = 'pointer'; 
    
    
    }
    if(counter==0){
        counter1();
        
        
        }

}, 1000);

}
```

I am making a function where a button will be disabled after clicked but the above counter automatically enables the buttons but i want both of them to be executed i. E. Disable a button after clicked and also disable if  the timer is going on and also to enable the buttons if the button is not clicked

Comment: `also to enable the buttons if the button is not clicked` you can't click on a button that is disabled.

Comment: I want the button to be enabled if it isn't clicked within the countdown and disable if the countdown is going but the button is clicked is it not possible?

Comment: i'll add an answer, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const myButton = document.getElementById('my-button');
  const status = document.getElementById('status');

  let counter = 10;
  let timerHandle;
  myButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    status.innerText = `Button will enable in ${counter} seconds`;

    myButton.disabled = true;

    timerHandle = setInterval(() => {
      counter--;
      status.innerText = `Button will enable in ${counter} seconds`;

      if (counter === 0) {
        clearInterval(timerHandle);
        status.innerText = `Timer cleared.`;
        myButton.disabled = false;
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    p {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <p id="status"></p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button id="my-button">Button</button>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('button');
elem.addEventListener('click',buttonClicked);

function buttonClicked(){
//do stuff 
 console.log("clicked")
 elem.disabled = true;
 setTimeout(() => {elem.disabled  =false}, 500);
}
```